# Renaming files in a folder (and subfolders) by removing a token in filename

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting

I have a *huge* amount of files in a folder (and subfolders) that I need to rename. For example, I have:

movie1.mp4 
fixed_movie1.mp4 
...

What I need is to rename fixed_movie1.mp4 to movie1.mp4 (thus overwriting the original file).

What I have so far:

```
TARGET_FILES=$(find /path/to -type f -name=*.mp4)
for f in $TARGET_FILES
do
  <some commands>
done
```

I know how to use sed (not too much I admit!) but I have problem using it because the fixed_ token is not always at the beginning of the string (looking in subfolders adds to the path).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `sed`. Bash can do Parameter Expansion:

```
for f in $TARGET_FILES ; do
    mv $f ${f/fixed_}
done
```

If your file names contain spaces, you should be more careful. Create a script to rename a file

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@" ; do
    mv "$f" "${f/fixed_}"
done
```

And run

```
find /path/to -type f -name=*.mp4 -exec /path/to/script.sh {} +
```

If `+` is not supported in your version of `find`, you can remove the loop from the script and rename the files one by one by using `\;` instead.

(If your `find` supports the `-execdir` option, you can use it to prevent situations where the path itself contains `fixed_`).